# Robot Frame Work:: Gherkin execution error

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

I wrote my First Gherkin Script (first.robot) when running same i am getting `"No keyword with name 'Given' found."` Error. Is there any Library i have to include or should i do any pip install something??

```
***
Gherkin Style TC
   [Documentation]  Let me try this time
    Given  Environement Setup Ready
    When  Required URL Get Loaded
    Then  Wait For Meters List to Appear
    And  Capture the list of Meters
    Then  CloseBrowser

***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two spaces after `Given` (and the others) but robot uses two spaces to separate keywords from arguments. You must have only one space after `Given`, `When`, etc. otherwise robot will think that `Given` is a keyword.

```
Gherkin Style TC
     [Documentation]  Let me try this time
     Given Environement Setup Ready
     When Required URL Get Loaded
     Then Wait For Meters List to Appear
     And Capture the list of Meters
     Then CloseBrowser
```

Some people add extra space before the given/when/then to make things line up nicely:

```
Gherkin Style TC
     [Documentation]  Let me try this time
     Given Environement Setup Ready
      When Required URL Get Loaded
      Then Wait For Meters List to Appear
       And Capture the list of Meters
      Then CloseBrowser
```

Comment: Wow man. You are man of Solutions.. thanks a lot. I been struggling to find what mistake i did.